# Do not change the datagridview while editing a column from the database

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, datagridviewcolumn

I have a form for editing database columns. When editing is done and I'm not editing the form, it does not change in the main Grid View form., even though I've written that code. It changes if I restart the software.

```
private void RefreshData()
{
    NewMainDataGridView.DataSource = BLL.View().Select(a => new { a.Id, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.PhoneNumber }).ToList();
}
  private void MainForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RefreshData();
}
```

More details about my question:

> My problem is not updating the data grid after changing the information of a column.
>   For example, in the sql server, for example, I edit the name of the customer or the last name but there is no change in my data grid, and I have to re-run the program I have written to see the change. This problem is for editing only when I have a I delete the customer from the database. This change will apply without rebooting the application.
>   I wrote a code to read the database again when my main form was active, but as I said, it does not happen during editing.

Comment: @Mndi, can you please explain your problem broadly? It is really difficult to understand your problem from this explanation. Are you facing problem with updating data?

Comment: @gypsyCoder : I edited the question and provided more explanations for my problem

Answer (score 0):

If Your are using MDI Child form.It dose not Refresh.
Active Event not work mdi forms.

Comment: I am removing a row from a table and returning to the original form where the active code is written. Changes apply. But when I edit a column from a table, it does not change.

Comment: because after the edit.your Activated event is fire so your code not work. just commit the active event and try again.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by this statement "commit " , How can I use it?